# (reference request) order of map in homotopy theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

If $f:X\to Y$ is a map and Y is a H-space then [X,Y] is monoid so we can define the order of $f$ as the order of $[f]\in [X,Y]$.
Is there a learning book where I can find this notion explained? For example, I need to know if f:X\to Y has order $m$ and if $g:Y\to Z$ has order  $n$, what can be say about order of $g\circ f$?
Or if I know orders of two of $f$, $g$, and $g\circ f$, what can I say about the third?

Comment: Certainly you will need $Z$ to have an $H$-space structure, and the map $g$ to be reasonable with respect to this structure. In that case, you can say something. But I doubt there's any book about "orders of maps with values in H-spaces"

Comment: I don't mean the whole book must be about it, maybe just a chapter is ok, or survey paper

Comment: Note that you need both $Y,Z$ to be H-spaces for your problem to make sense. Also observe that the order of a map may be infinite (take $X=Y=S^1$). It is possible for $ord(f)=ord(g)=\infty$ and for $g\circ f$ to be trivial (take $X=Y=S^1\times S^1$ and let $f,g$ be the projections onto the two factors). Assuming both $Y,Z$ are H-spaces, for any integer $n$ you have $n\cdot(g\circ f)=(n\cdot g)\circ f$. Thus $ord(g\circ f)$ is bounded above by $ord(g)$. On the other hand it is possible for $ord(g\circ f)$ to be greater than $ord(f)$.